# When I enable a HashiCorp Vault secrets engine e.g. kv and add a secret is this accessible across vault users?

Tags: security, hashicorp-vault

When I enable a HashiCorp Vault secrets engine e.g. kv and add a secret, is this accessible across vault users? If I add the secrets engine as the root user, is this accessible to any users that I add to HashiCorp Vault?

My thought seems to defeat the purpose of vault but I am trying to get an idea if a user creates a secret and it's embedded within an application and that employee leaves the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I enable a HashiCorp Vault secrets engine e.g. kv and add a secret, is this accessible across vault users?

Each user has permissions attached to her, they are called policies. If those permissions allow access, then, the user has access.

You might want to check the official documentation out https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies

> If I add the secrets engine as the root user, is this accessible to any users that I add to HashiCorp Vault?

It doesnt matter who creates the secrets (hint: its not recommended using root for anything than the initial setup).

To give you an example, you can have users that can create secrets

```
path "kv/foo" {
  capabilities = ["create"]
}
```

and users that can only consume them, for example

```
path "kv/foo" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
```